# Image title not displaying in Preetyphoto intergration with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery

I used Prettyphoto integration to my word-press site,
I am having problem to display title and description of an image in prettyphoto. I discovered that the problem is when I edit a gallery (in media) I can see that all the images have titles, and other fields filled in but those titles no longer display when the gallery is viewed in light-box using prettyphoto.
here is HTML for img

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `functions.php`

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'rc_add_rel_attribute');
    function rc_add_rel_attribute($link) {
    global $post;
   return str_replace('<a href', '<a rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" href', $link);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me the link of your website? I just want to know the `HTML` structure of your gallery.